# Java RMI Exception creating connection when used on != machines

Tags: java, callback, rmi

I've been struggling with a RMI problem for a couple of hours now. Its a pretty stupid example for now that only works when I launch the both the client & server on the same computer. As soon as I launch the client ^ server on a != machine, i get an exception when the server tries to call the callback :

```
Exception creating connection to: 192.168.244.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:632)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:128)
```

Which by the way does not make any sense since i'm on a 10.0.0.x subnet, where does this IP comes from ?

The code is composed of two classes, Server & Client, implementing two {Server|Client}Interfaces. I have no problem getting the server object from the RMIRegistry, and calling the login method. I can see with a breakpoint in the server side that the code is executed, however as soon as it comes to the callback instruction it fails. The exception is client-side btw.

I tried disabling firewall on both machines with no success. I suspect that the problem comes from the ip the exception sends me, but I can't figure out where does it comes from.

Here is the following code :
(Client.java)

```
public class Client extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ClientInterface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Client();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Client() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, NotBoundException {
        ServerInterface s = null;
        s = (ServerInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://10.0.0.48/server");
        s.login(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void talk() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("Talkiiiing");
    }
}
```

(ClientInterface.java)

```
public interface ClientInterface extends Remote {
    void talk() throws RemoteException;;
}
```

(Server.java)

```
public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface {

    public Server() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/server", this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Server();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void login(ClientInterface clientInterface) throws RemoteException {
        clientInterface.talk();
    }
}
```

And finally the (ServerInterface.java)

```
public interface ServerInterface extends Remote {
    void login(ClientInterface clientInterface)  throws RemoteException;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic java.rmi.server.hostname problem. See [item A.1 in the RMI FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#domain). You need to set java.rmi.server.hostname at the server JVM to the address you want your clients to use when connecting. The problem is caused by a misconfigured DNS: maybe you can fix it there instead: better if you can. 'localhost' should resolve to 127.0.0.1 and your hostname should resolve to your real IP address.

Comment: I dont really see where/why DNS is called here. I've tried to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 without any success. I think the problem A.1 happens when you aren't able to do the Naming.Loockup(..). However I am, the problem happens when the remote method on the server tries to call a client's callback. EDIT : I've tried what you suggested and I still have the same exception :(

Comment: @user1729268 If your problem happens when trying the callback, it is the client's IP address and DNS that is the problem. In this case you have to set java.rmi.server.hostname at the client JVM to the IP address you want the server to use. The reason is that the client is also a server from the point of view of the callback. If the client is behind a firewall or NAT device it won't work anyway unless inbound ports are forwarded, and you would have to set java.rmi.server.hostname to the IP address of the NAT device.

Comment: @user1729268 DNS is called to embed the current hostname into the stub when the remote object is exported. As to the rest, you are you are arguing with the Oracle RMI FAQ, and you are wrong on all counts. Problem A.1 happens when you have an incorrect DNS. It shows up when you do the remote call, not on Naming.lookup(). This is all as per the FAQ. Changing between localhost and 127.0.0.1 can have no effect, and I don't know why you even tried it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to add -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.0.0.48 in the VM options in Intellij IDEA, but its still not working. Is there a way to do that programatically ?

Comment: @user1729268 System.setProperty(), but you have to call it before exporting any remote objects, including Registries.

Comment: My bad, i was trying to do that serverside. Now its working. Thanks a lot for your help !